# Unit Testing with ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js

I am trying to unit test my ExpressJS routes. It looks something like this

server.js

```
var boards = require('./routes/BoardsRoute.js');
app.get('/api/v1/boards/:id', boards.getBoard);
```

BoardRoutes.js

```
exports.getBoard = function(req, res) {
  BoardModel.find({
        name: 'Kanban Board'
    }, function(err, columns) {
    if (!err) {
        return res.send(columns);
    } else {
        return console.log(err);
    }
});
return res.send(board);
};
```

I would like to Mock out the BoardModel as this is the call to the Mongoose Model (aka Database call). As I assume that unit tests should not be making calls to a database and have no server running.

Should I be testing the getBoards completely seperatly to the server.js app.get() call.
(As these requests apt.get will be covered by integration tests/e2e tests and they are HTTP requests)

All the documentation and frameworks that I can see either have to have Express Server running in order to unit test the route and this particular exports.getBoard.

Things that I have tried to do,

Use Sinon.js to mock a fakeServer so that I could test the HTTP Request and the method getBoard.

Use SuperAgent and Super Test to make the requests out to a server. (I am uncomfortable with this as unit tests should not have a server running).

I am trying to use Mocha to test these routes.

Answer (score -1):

I would test that the route is wired up correctly first, then test that the call to the route does what you expect.

To test the route here's one way you could do it. Create a routes module that just wires up the routes:

```
var routes = {};                                                                                                           

routes.create = function(app) {                                                                                                                                                                                     
   app.get('/api/v1/boards/:id', boards.getBoard);
}

module.exports = routes;
```

You can then mock the app object and check the get method gets called correctly. (I tend to use Sinon.js for this.) The create method will need to be called from your app module:

```
var app = express();
... // set up express
routes.create(app);
```

Now you can focus on testing getBoard on its own like any other module.

Comment: The answer would be useful if code had been provided on how to test if "wired up" correctly.